# Electrostatic induction

Tags: electrostatics, charge

Is this a correct definition of electrostatic induction, The **production** of opposite charges on a neutral body when a charged body is brought near to it? I think it's not the production but redistribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charge is conserved, so it is never "produced". You are correct that it is redistributed in the scenario you describe, which is sometimes called electrostatic induction, not to be confused with electromagnetic induction.

Answer (score 0):

Induction is the process of appearance of opposite charge on the surface of a neutral conductor,when a charged body is brought near it.

Comment: The question asks for the *mechanism* of this appearance of charge.